# How can I sort the output of 'ls' by last modified date?

Tags: linux, unix, shell, ls

How can I sort the output of `ls` by last modified date?

Comment: Related (not necessarily a duplicate): *[Unix/Linux find and sort by date modified](http://superuser.com/questions/294161)*

Answer (score 2090):

```
ls -t
```

or (for reverse, most recent at bottom):

```
ls -tr
```

The [`ls` man page](https://ss64.com/bash/ls.html) describes this in more details, and lists other options.

Comment: `ls -halt` is for `human readable`, `show hidden`, `print details`, `sort by date`.

Comment: In case anyone's wondering, both the `-t` and `-r` arguments are specified in [the section about `ls` in the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ls.html), so should be compatible across Unices.

Comment: `ls -llt` for showing date-timestamp along with sorting

Comment: Is it possible to just show file name & date for each?

Comment: Yes it is possible

Comment: Note that this argument is also applicable to `ll`.

Comment: @EvgeniSergeev DONT MEMORISE `ls -halt` a simple mistype may cause your server to crash! https://linux.die.net/man/8/halt

Comment: @Isaac: for a regular user `halt` is not gonna work without `sudo` unless explicitly configured.

Comment: Yea, because _nobody_ would ever run as root...

Comment: @Isaac if you mistype ls -halt you're still just running ls....

Comment: Unless you mistype it as `ls ;halt`

Comment: i prefer use `ll -ltr` , its would print in `K` for size of file instead of `byte`

Comment: @Isaac yeah and be very careful because you can also mistype it as `sudo rm -rf /`

Answer (score 186):

Try this: `ls -ltr`. It will give you the recent to the end of the list

Comment: I used this to get the list of files in my Git repository by their last edit date. `ls -alt $(git ls-files -m)` Thanks!

Answer (score 56):

For a complete answer here is what I use: `ls -lrth`

Put this in your startup script `/etc/bashrc` and assign an alias like this: `alias l='ls -lrth'` Restart your terminal and you should be able to type `l` and see a long list of files.

Comment: You can also call `source /etc/bashrc` if you want to add it to your repertoire while running.

Comment: You can also add it in `~/.bash_aliases` just for your user (one can create the file if it doesn't exist already

Answer (score 40):

### I use sometime this:

```
find . -type f -mmin -5 -print0 | xargs -0 /bin/ls -tr
```

or

```
find . -type f -mmin -5 -print0 | xargs -0 /bin/ls -ltr
```

to look **recursively** for which files were modified in last 5 minutes.

... or now, with recent version of *GNU find*:

```
find . -type f -mmin -5 -exec ls -ltr {} +
```

... and even *for not limiting to files*:

```
find . -mmin -5 -exec ls -ltrd {} +
```

(note the `-d` switch to `ls` for not displaying content of directories)

### More robust way?

Have a look at [my answer to *find and sort by date modified*](https://superuser.com/a/1481352/178656)

Comment: By recursively you mean it lists all files in subdirectories, doesn't ls already have a switch to do that?

Comment: @jiggunjer `ls -Rltr` will sort by dir, then by dates, `find -type f -mmin -5 -exec ls -ltr {} +` will just print files modified in last 5 minutes, sorted by date, regardless of directory tree!

Comment: Note that this won't work if the list of files is too long to be passed as one shell invocation to `ls` (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/118200/27186) – then you'll see one sorted bunch of files, then another sorted bunch of files, etc. but the whole list won't be sorted. See https://superuser.com/questions/294161/unix-linux-find-and-sort-by-date-modified for sorting longer lists with find.

Comment: @unhammer You're right, for this to work safely, see [my recent anser to  Unix/Linux find and sort by date modified](https://superuser.com/a/1481352/178656)

Answer (score 24):

Add:

```
alias lt='ls -Alhtr'
```

in `$homedir/.bashrc`

Answer (score 24):

## Mnemonic

For don't ignore entries starting with `.` and **sort by date** (newest first):

```
ls -at
```

For don't ignore entries starting with `.` and **reverse sort by date** (oldest first):

```
ls -art
```

For don't ignore entries starting with `.`, use a long listing format and **sort by date** (newest first):

```
ls -alt
```

For print human readable sizes, don't ignore entries starting with `.`, use a long listing format and **sort by date** (newest first) (@EvgeniSergeev note):

```
ls -halt
```

but **be careful with the last one**, because a simple mistype can cause a server crash... (@Isaac note)

Answer (score 18):

Find all files on the file system that were modified maximally 3 * 24 hours (3 days) ago till now:

```
find / -ctime 3
```

Answer (score 15):

To show 10 most recent sorted by date, I use something like this:

```
ls -t ~/Downloads | head -10
```

or to show oldest

```
ls -tr ~/Downloads | tail -10
```

Comment: it giv`ls -t head -2` and `ls -tr | tail -2` gives same result, option (-t/-tr) should be kept fixed and modified the tail/head or vice verse, modifing both is like modyfing nothing

Comment: Did you see the comment above? Indeed, one should use `head` in both commands (to change the sort order too), or use `ls -t` in both commands (which would always sort descending by date).

Answer (score 10):

Using only very basic Unix commands:

```
ls -nl | sort -k 8,8n -k 6,6M
```

This worked on Linux; column 8 is "n" (numeric), column 6 is "M", month.

I'm new at `sort`, so this answer could probably be improved. Not to mention, it needs additional options to `ls` and `sort` to use exact timestamps, but not everyone will need this.

Comment: I suspect your answer hasn't gotten any up-votes because it parses the output of ls - see [the canonical argument against doing so](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and [this question about not parsing ls](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Answer (score 6):

One possible way of showing for example last 10 modified files is following command:

```
ls -lrth | tail -n 10
```

*Description of above command:*

```
ls - list
```

arguments:

```
l - long
r - reverse
t - sort by time
h - human readable
```

then it's piped to `tail` command, which shows
only 10 recent lines, defined by **n** parameter (number of lines)...