# Unix/Linux find and sort by date modified

Tags: linux, unix, sorting, find

How can I do a simple `find` which would order the results by most recently modified?

Here is the current `find` I am using (I am doing a shell escape in PHP, so that is the reasoning for the variables):

```
find '$dir' -name '$str'\* -print | head -10
```

How could I have this order the search by most recently modified? (Note I do not want it to sort 'after' the search, but rather find the results based on what was most recently modified.)

Comment: https://github.com/shadkam/recentmost/ would do what is desired - but one needs to build it

Answer (score 344):

Use this:

```
find . -printf "%T@ %Tc %p\n" | sort -n
```

`printf` arguments from [`man find`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find):

- `%Tk`: File's last modification time in the format specified by `k`.
- `@`: seconds since Jan. 1, 1970, 00:00 GMT, with fractional part.
- `c`: locale's date and time (Sat Nov 04 12:02:33 EST 1989).
- `%p`: File's name.

Comment: +1 Very useful, the first answer to this I have found with a readable/useful date output

Comment: most reliable (and very simple) as the time is granted to be numerically sequential (therefore always properly sortable), thx!

Comment: I have this alias for finding recent files in my `~/.zshrc`: `fr () { find ./ -iname "*"$@"*" -printf "%T@ %Td-%Tb-%TY %Tk:%TM %p\n" | sort -n | cut -d " " -f 2- | grep -i "$@" ; }` It recursively finds all files containing the pattern of the first argument passed to the command (`fr <pattern>`) and sorts them with the most recent one last.

Comment: This is great !!! To use with symlinks, use `find -L ... `

Comment: You may want to use `ssed` to get rid of the seconds fractional part and stil use ISO8601 as @PeterMortensen showed : `find . -type f -printf "%TY-%Tm-%TdT%TT %p\n" | sort -r | ssed -R 's/^([^.]+)\.\d+ (.*)$/\1 \2/'`

Comment: @joelostblom JFYI, instead of `cut -d " " -f 2-` you may want to use `cut -d " " -f 1 --complement` but it is longer.

Comment: For [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date output with ***time zone information***, use `find . -printf "%TY-%Tm-%TdT%TT %TZ %p\n" `. As it sorts naturally, it can also, like the Unix time in this answer, be used directly in the sort: `find . -printf "%TY-%Tm-%TdT%TT %TZ %p\n" | sort -n`. Note that the date information is not in ISO 8601 format (e.g. "CEDT" - Central European Daylight Time). (*My original comment (now deleted) had a number of flaws, in particular the use of the access time instead of the modification time.*)

Comment: Note that for OSX one has to use the GNU version `gfind` instead of `find`, since `printf` is not part of `POSIX` `find`. It can be installed with `brew install findutils`.

Comment: getting the error `paths must precede expression`? Make sure you got `-printf` and not `-print`

Comment: Why not just use `"%T+ %p\n"`, `%T+` include date and time with fractional seconds

Comment: i like this solution and added ` | cut -d' ' -f2-` to get rid of the sort column in the final output.

Comment: Thank you, contrary to many other answers this works when find has multiple search directories

Answer (score 98):

The easiest method is to use zsh, thanks to its [glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers).

```sh
print -lr -- $dir/**/$str*(om[1,10])
```

If you have GNU find, make it print the file modification times and sort by that.

```sh
find -type f -printf '%T@ %p\0' |
sort -zk 1nr |
sed -z 's/^[^ ]* //' | tr '\0' '\n' | head -n 10
```

If you have GNU find but not other GNU utilities, use newlines as separators instead of nulls; you'll lose support for filenames containing newlines.

```sh
find -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n' |
sort -k 1nr |
sed 's/^[^ ]* //' | head -n 10
```

If you have Perl (here I'll assume there are no newlines in file names):

```sh
find . -type f -print |
perl -l -ne '
    $_{$_} = -M;  # store file age (mtime - now)
    END {
        $,="\n";
        @sorted = sort {$_{$a} <=> $_{$b}} keys %_;  # sort by increasing age
        print @sorted[0..9];
    }'
```

If you have Python (also assuming no newlines in file names):

```sh
find . -type f -print |
python -c 'import os, sys; times = {}
for f in sys.stdin.readlines(): f = f[0:-1]; times[f] = os.stat(f).st_mtime
for f in (sorted(times.iterkeys(), key=lambda f:times[f], reverse=True))[:10]: print(f)'
```

There's probably a way to do the same in PHP, but I don't know it.

If you want to work with only POSIX tools, it's rather more complicated; see [How to list files sorted by modification date recursively (no stat command available!)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9247/how-to-list-files-sorted-by-modification-date-recursively-no-stat-command-availa) (retatining the first 10 is the easy part).

Comment: I think the `find` version shows the oldest files, and that you need to add the `-r` option to `sort`.

Comment: My sed says it doesn't have a -z option.

Comment: @KefSchecter Then use newlines as separators, but you'll lose support for newlines in file names.

Comment: The above is for python2. If you only have python3, some small changes: python3 -c 'import os, sys; times = {}
for f in sys.stdin.readlines(): f = f[0:-1]; times[f] = os.stat(f).st_mtime
for f in (sorted(times.keys(), key=lambda f:times[f], reverse=True))[:10]: print(f);'

Comment: Your #2 solution works (it's the only one I've tried). The answer checked as "valid" doen't work properly (not the last touched files).

Comment: As "python" is not a stable language, you should always write even oneliners with `python2` or  `python3` instead.

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen Back when I wrote this answer, Python 3 was still pretty new and uncommon. Later, some systems decided only ship `python`, so explicitly calling `python2` or `python3` is unfortunately not portable either.

Comment: Yeah, people once believed that "python" was a stable language but Python designers decided to break backwards compatibility and we're here to collect pieces. Nowadays oneliners must explicitly say `python2` or `python3` unless the code is specifically compatible with all Python versions (including future ones because there's already precedent for breaking backwards compatibility).

Answer (score 61):

You don't need to PHP or Python, just [ls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ls):

```
man ls:
-t     sort by modification time
-r,    reverse order while sorting (--reverse )
-1     list one file per line

find /wherever/your/files/hide -type f -exec ls -1rt "{}" +;
```

If command * exits with a failure status (ie **Argument list too long**), then you can iterate with find. Paraphrased from: [The maximum length of arguments for a new process](http://www.in-ulm.de/%7Emascheck/various/argmax/)

- `find . -print0|xargs -0 command`      (optimizes speed, if find doesn't implement "-exec +" but knows "-print0")
- `find . -print|xargs command`     (if there's no white space in the arguments)

If the major part of the arguments consists of long, absolute or relative paths, then try to move your actions into the directory: `cd /directory/with/long/path; command *` And another quick fix may be to match fewer arguments: `command [a-e]*; command [f-m]*; ...`

---

*2023 update*

The xargs solution does not really work, because it will output in several batches, so you would find the latest file in each batch, as opposed to the latest file of all.

A practical solution with gnu-find can be found in my [local-bin repo](https://github.com/tox2ik/local-bin/blob/master/.probably-useful/find-latest):

reproduced here:

```
#!/bin/bash
function strip_1() { awk ' BEGIN{ RS="\0"} { $1="" ; gsub(/^\s/,"", $0); print }'; }
function strip_1n() { awk '{ $1="" ; gsub(/^\s/,"", $0); print }'; }
function n2z() { tr \\n \\0; }
find=/usr/bin/find
if [[ $0 == *latest0 ]]; then
    $find ${1:-./} -not -path '*/.git/*' -type f -printf "%T@ %p\0" | sort -nz | n2z | strip_1 | n2z
else
    $find ${1:-./} -not -path '*/.git/*' -type f -printf "%T@ %p\n" | sort -n | strip_1n
fi
```

Comment: If there are a lot of files, this fails with 'Argument list too long' on the ls.

Comment: That's true, but I believe the question was "how do I do a simple find..."

Comment: ls doesn't quote file names in a way xargs can understand (no -0 option, and the various quote styles are inadequate)

Comment: This blog post explains and expands on the solution: https://www.elsewebdevelopment.com/linux-one-liners-using-the-standard-find-command-to-replace-3rd-party-fuzzy-finders/

Answer (score 22):

I have a simple solution that works for both FreeBSD (OS X) and Linux:

```
find . -type f -exec ls -t {} +
```

Comment: This works perfectly - should be correct answer, or at least higher rated!

Comment: `find . -type f -exec ls -lat {} +` gives you a better picture with date and time showing if somebody needs this format

Comment: This should be the best answer. Simple, easy to understand. The key is the plus sign in the end. This allows the `find` to call `ls` once only.

Comment: Only works reliably as long as all filenames returned by `find .` fit on one command line, subject to the platform's [`ARG_MAX`](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/).

Answer (score 19):

Extending [user195696's answer](https://superuser.com/a/546900/141883):

```
find . -type f -printf "%T@\t%Tc %6k KiB %p\n" | sort -n | cut -f 2-
```

For each file, this first outputs the numeric timestamp (for sorting by, followed by tabulation `\t`), then a human-readable timestamp, then the filesize (unfortunately `find`'s `-printf` can't do in mebibytes, only kibibytes), then the filename with relative path.

Then `sort -n` sorts it by the first numeric field.

Then `cut` gets rid of that first numeric field which is of no interest to the user. (Prints second field onward.) The default field separator is `\t` or tabulation.

Example of output:

```
Thu 06 Feb 2014 04:49:14 PM EST     64 KiB ./057_h2_f7_10/h2_f7_10.class
Fri 07 Feb 2014 02:08:30 AM EST 7962976 KiB ./056_h2_f7_400/h2__rh_4e-4.mph
Fri 07 Feb 2014 02:23:24 AM EST 7962976 KiB ./056_h2_f7_400/h2_f7_400_out_Model.mph
Fri 07 Feb 2014 02:23:24 AM EST      0 KiB ./056_h2_f7_400/h2_f7_400_out.mph.status
Fri 07 Feb 2014 02:23:24 AM EST     64 KiB ./056_h2_f7_400/1579678.out
Fri 07 Feb 2014 03:47:31 AM EST 8132224 KiB ./057_h2_f7_10/h2__rh_1e-5.mph
Fri 07 Feb 2014 04:00:49 AM EST 8132224 KiB ./057_h2_f7_10/h2_f7_10_out_Model.mph
Fri 07 Feb 2014 04:00:49 AM EST      0 KiB ./057_h2_f7_10/h2_f7_10_out.mph.status
Fri 07 Feb 2014 04:00:49 AM EST     64 KiB ./057_h2_f7_10/1579679.out
Fri 07 Feb 2014 09:47:18 AM EST   9280 KiB ./056_h2_f7_400/h2__rh_4e-4.mat
Fri 07 Feb 2014 10:51:23 AM EST   9728 KiB ./018_bidomain/h2_plain__rh_1e-5.mat
Fri 07 Feb 2014 10:58:33 AM EST   9568 KiB ./057_h2_f7_10/h2__rh_1e-5.mat
Fri 07 Feb 2014 05:05:38 PM EST     64 KiB ./058_h2_f7_stationary/h2_f7_stationary.java
Fri 07 Feb 2014 06:06:29 PM EST     32 KiB ./058_h2_f7_stationary/slurm.slurm
Sat 08 Feb 2014 03:42:07 AM EST      0 KiB ./058_h2_f7_stationary/1581061.err
Sat 08 Feb 2014 03:42:14 AM EST     64 KiB ./058_h2_f7_stationary/h2_f7_stationary.class
Sat 08 Feb 2014 03:58:28 AM EST  70016 KiB ./058_h2_f7_stationary/h2s__rh_1e-5.mph
Sat 08 Feb 2014 04:12:40 AM EST  70304 KiB ./058_h2_f7_stationary/h2s__rh_4e-4.mph
Sat 08 Feb 2014 04:12:53 AM EST  70304 KiB ./058_h2_f7_stationary/h2_f7_stationary_out_Model.mph
Sat 08 Feb 2014 04:12:53 AM EST      0 KiB ./058_h2_f7_stationary/h2_f7_stationary_out.mph.status
Sat 08 Feb 2014 04:12:53 AM EST     32 KiB ./058_h2_f7_stationary/1581061.out
Mon 10 Feb 2014 11:40:54 AM EST    224 KiB ./058_h2_f7_stationary/h2s__rh_4e-4.mat
Mon 10 Feb 2014 11:42:32 AM EST    224 KiB ./058_h2_f7_stationary/h2s__rh_1e-5.mat
Mon 10 Feb 2014 11:50:08 AM EST     32 KiB ./plot_grid.m
```

I deliberately made the filesize field 6 characters, because if making it longer, it becomes hard to visually distinguish how large the files are. This way, files larger than 1e6 KiB jut out: by 1 char means 1-9 GB, by 2 chars means 10-99 GB, etc.

---

Edit: here's another version (since `find . -printf "%Tc"` crashes on MinGW/MSYS):

```
find . -type f -printf "%T@\t%p\n" | sort -n | cut -f 2- | xargs -I{} ls -Glath --si {}
```

Giving output like:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 es 23K Jul 10  2010 ./laptop_0000071.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 es 43M Jul 29 19:19 ./work.xcf
-rw-r--r-- 1 es 87K Jul 29 20:11 ./patent_lamps/US Patent 274427 Maxim Lamp Holder.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 es 151K Jul 29 20:12 ./patent_lamps/Edison screw-in socket.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 es 50K Jul 29 20:13 ./patent_lamps/1157 Lamp.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 es 38K Jul 29 20:14 ./patent_lamps/US06919684-20050719-D00001.png
```

Where:

- `-I{}` causes the occurrence of `{}` to be replaced by an argument, **and** newlines are now the argument separators (note the spaces in filenames above).
- `ls -G` suppresses printing the group name (waste of space).
- `ls -h --si` produces human-readable file sizes (more correct with `--si`).
- `ls -t` sorts by time, which is irrelevant here, but that's what I typically use.

Comment: Note: to sort by file **size** instead, simply replace the `T@` by `s` in either of the above commands.

Comment: this one seems to be the quickest

Comment: Note that this doesn't support linefeeds in filenames.

Answer (score 13):

You do only need [ls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ls)

You could do `find /wherever/your/files/hide -type f -exec ls -1rt "{}" +;` as stated above,

or

```
ls -1rt `find /wherever/your/file/hides -type f`
```

Comment: If there are a lot of files, this fails with 'Argument list too long' on the ls. Maybe recook to use xargs?

Comment: But if `xargs` calls `ls` multiple times, the sort will be broken.

Comment: This fails for files with spaces in their names. Any advice?

Comment: Just stumbled upon this answer and it was exactly what I needed in a similar situation. Question: what does the `+;` at the end do? It seems to give the same result without the `;` however it does not work without the `+` ?

Comment: This is just the same as another answer posted 8 months before, except for the part about using "ls -1rt \`find …\`", which is broken

Answer (score 7):

OS X variant of [@user195696's answer](https://superuser.com/a/546900/150988):

1. With timestamp:

   ```
    find . -type f -exec stat -f "%Sm %N" -t "%Y%y%m%d%H%M" {} \; | sort -r
   ```
2. Without timestamp:

   ```
    find . -type f -exec stat -f "%Sm %N" -t "%Y%y%m%d%H%M" {} \; | sort -r | awk -F' ' '{ print substr($0, length($1) + 2) }'
   ```

   or, alternatively,

   ```
    find . -type f -exec stat -f "%Sm %N" -t "%Y%y%m%d%H%M" {} \; | sort -r | cut -d ' ' -f2-
   ```

As with many of the other answers,
this will fail for filenames that contain newline(s),
but it should work for filenames that contain (horizontal) whitespace.

Answer (score 4):

### Here is a clean and robust way for `sort | head` by date:

Using `ls -l` for pretty print

```
find . ! -type d -printf "%T@ %p\0" |
    sort -zrn |
    head -zn 10 |
    sed -z 's/^[0-9.]\+ //' |
    xargs -0 ls -lt
```

### As a [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) function:

```
findByDate() {
    local humansize=''
    [ "$1" = "-h" ] && humansize='h' && shift
    find . ${2:-! -type d} -printf "%T@ %p\0" |
        sort -zrn |
        head -zn ${1:--0} |
        sed -z 's/^[0-9.]\+ //' |
        xargs -0 ls -dlt${humansize}
}
```

This could by run with one or two argument, or even without:

```
Usage: findByDate [-h] [lines] [find options]
```

Sample:

```
findByDate
```

Will list all *non directories* sorted by date. Nota:

Even on big filesystem tree, as `xargs`  recieve already sorted list, the file order stay correct, even if `ls` must be run many times.

```
findByDate -h 12
```

Will list 12 more recents *non directories* sorted by date, with size printed in *human readable* form

```
findByDate 42 '-type l'
```

Will list 42 more recents symlinks

```
findByDate -0 '( -type l -o -type b -o -type s -o -type c )'
```

Will list all symlinks, block devices, sockets and characters devices, sorted by date.

### Inverting order

Replacing `head` by `tail` and change switch of `sort` and `ls`:

```
findByDate() {
    local humansize=''
    [ "$1" = "-h" ] && humansize='h' && shift
    find . ${2:-! -type d} -printf "%T@ %p\0" |
        sort -zn |
        tail -zn ${1:-+0} |
        sed -z 's/^[0-9.]\+ //' |
        xargs -0 ls -dltr${humansize}
}
```

Same function, same usage:

```
Usage: findByDate [-h] [lines] [find options]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
find '$dir' -name '$str'\* -print | xargs ls -tl | head -10
```

But it's also useful to filter data by `-mmin`/`-mtime` and `-type`.

Answer (score 2):

I found that this gets the job done on Mac OS X (and generic enough to work on other Unixen as well):

```
find . -type f -ls | awk '{print $(NF-3), $(NF-2), $(NF-1), $NF}' | sort
```

Comment: Sadly, this prints out localized month names on my Croatian setup, making sort incorrect.

Comment: [user195696's answer](http://superuser.com/questions/294161/unix-linux-find-and-sort-by-date-modified/546900#546900) works for the Croatian setup (and others).

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
find . -type f -mtime 0 -printf "[%TD %TI:%TM%Tp] %s %p\n" | sort -n | awk '{
    hum[1024**4]="TB"; hum[1024**3]="GB"; hum[1024**2]="MB"; hum[1024]="KB"; hum[0]="B";
    for (x=1024**4; x>=1024; x/=1024){
    if ($3>=x) { printf $1" "$2"\t%7.2f %s\t%s\n",$3/x,hum[x],$4;break }
    }}';
```

This command will sort files by modified date.

And display out like:

```
[12/05/13 03:10PM] 1.75 MB ./file.text
[12/06/13 11:52PM] 2.90 MB ./file2.mp4
[12/07/13 04:11PM] 4.88 MB ./file3.mp4
[12/07/13 09:17PM] 4.74 MB ./test.apk
```

Comment: I improved this sript to handle whitespace in filenames, see http://superuser.com/a/777007/134532

Answer (score 1):

If your `find` selection is very simple, you might be able to do without it, and just use `ls`:

```
ls -1 *.cc # -r -t optional
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `find` has any options to modify the output ordering.  `-mtime` and `-mmin` will let you restrict the results to files that have been modified within a certain time window, but the output won't be sorted -- you'll have to do that yourself. GNU `find` has a `-printf` option that, among other things,  will let you print the modification time of each file found (format strings `%t` or `%Tk`) ; that might help you sort the `find` output the way you wish.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to order all PNG files by time in `$PWD`:

This simple one-liner gives all the flexibility of regexp on `find` and on `ls`.

```
find $PWD -name "*.png" -print0 | xargs -0 ls -laht | less
```

Answer (score 0):

I improved Akashs answer by making the script handling whitespace in filenames correctly:

```
find . -type f -mtime 0 -printf ";[%TD %TI:%TM%Tp];%s;%p\n" | sort -n | awk -F ";" '{
    hum[1024**4]="TB"; hum[1024**3]="GB"; hum[1024**2]="MB"; hum[1024]="KB"; hum[0]="B";
    for (x=1024**4; x>=1024; x/=1024){
    if ($3>=x) { printf $1" "$2"\t%7.2f %s\t%s\n",$3/x,hum[x],$4;break }
    }}';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stat` on BSD and Linux (not on POSIX) in this fashion:

```
$ stat -f "%m%t%N" /[the dir]/* | sort -rn | cut -f2-
```

If you want to limit the number:

```
$ stat -f "%m%t%N" /[the dir]/* | sort -rn | head -[the number] | cut -f2-
```

Answer (score 0):

Much better and safer with `fd`:

```shell
fd "<regex>" "<dir>" --exec find {} -printf "%T@ %Td-%Tb-%TY %TT %p\n" |
 sort -n | cut -d " " -f 2-
```

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to get a full path of each item you can write down like this.

```
 find FIND_ROOT -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%T@ %p\n" | sort -nr | head -10 | cut -d ' ' -f 2
```

Where
**-printf "%T@ %p\n"** for giving sorting criteria (date),
**'sort -nr'** for sorting by date,
**head -10** for listing top 10 results,
**cut -d ' ' -f 2** for cutting the leading timestamp on each line.

Comment: `cut -d ' ' -f 2` will break if filenames contain spaces.

Answer (score -3):

I have a simple solution.

After `cd` to a directory, use

`find . -iname "*" -ls`

Comment: This doesn't sort by date modified.