# copy files from one directory to other in loop

Tags: linux, bash

I am not bash expert.
I need to write a script to copy latest (by date) file from one folder to another 
as following

from

```
/test/a/date1.bak
/test/a/date2.bak
/test/a/date3.bak 
/test/b/date1.bak
/test/b/date2.bak
/test/b/date3.bak
```

to

```
/test/a/sec/date1.bak
/test/b/sec/date1.bak
```

On the second step I need to delete oldest file by date in the destination directory

from

```
/test/a/sec/date1.bak
/test/a/sec/date2.bak
/test/b/sec/date1.bak
/test/b/sec/date2.bak
```

to

```
/test/a/sec/date1.bak
/test/b/sec/date1.bak
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unix/Linux find and sort by date modified](http://superuser.com/questions/294161/unix-linux-find-and-sort-by-date-modified)

Comment: Welcome to SU! We're not a script writing service. What have you got so far, and where exactly are you getting stuck?

Comment: I can copy and delete one by one                                        cp $(ls -1t | head -1) /test/a/secure/                  But I would like to do it in recursive way

Comment: Please show us the actual date format you are using. Do you want to extract (parse) the date from the file name or do you want to use the file's modification time?

Answer (score 0):

ok got it. Terdon I am need to use files modification date.  Here what I did for the file copy:

for BDIR in `ls -1 .`; do TO_BACK=$(ls -t $BDIR | grep ".bak$" | head -1); if [ "$TO_BACK" ]; then echo "copy $BDIR/$TO_BACK to $BDIR/sec/$TO_BACK"; fi; done