# Grep in newest file

Tags: unix, shell, shell-script, grep

I'm trying to find a specific line from the newest file I have in subfolders. Files have the same name. So structure is like:

- Folder

  - SubFolder1

    - filename.xml
  - SubFolder2

    - filename.xml

I'm using grep to have the line

```
grep -r "mySubString" folder/
```

I've try using find to sort files as proposed [here](https://superuser.com/questions/294161/unix-linux-find-and-sort-by-date-modified). But I don't know how to combine both to get just the line from the newest file.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: it is not clear whether you want to run `grep` on the latest file, even if it finds nothing, or whether you want the output from the latest file where `grep` finds a match.

Comment: Thanks AFH for your comment. I want to run the grep in the newest file.

Comment: In that case @ap0 gives the neatest answer below, but it will need modification if you want to know which of the files the string came from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find . -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n' | sort -n | tail -1 | cut -f2- -d" "
```

This will return the latest file created from the directory you are running this command from and all sub directories. If you want so search in a specific directory chane `.` to the directory path.

to grep for the content of this file:

```
cat `find . -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n' | sort -n | tail -1 | cut -f2- -d" "` | grep "mySubString"
```

Edit: I am not sure. I tryed this my self quickly and it worked. I created a test file and used this command. It worked for me. If there is a problem, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

zsh:

```
grep pattern **/*(.om[1])
```

`om` orders by modification date and `.` is a qualifier for regular files.

GNU `find`:

```
grep pattern "$(find -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n'|sort -n|tail -n1|cut -d' ' -f2-)"
```

`%T@` is modification time and `%p` is pathname.

BSD:

```
grep pattern "$(find . -type f -exec stat -f '%m %N' {} +|sort -n|tail -n1|cut -d' ' -f2-)"
```

`%m` is modification time and `%N` is pathname.

bash 4:

```
shopt -s globstar;grep pattern "$(ls -dt **|head -n1)"
```

This includes directories and can result in an argument list too long error.

Comment: This is right also, I can't upvote due to my low reputation.