# Find last edited directory in a bash script

Tags: bash, ls

I have been told never to parse `ls`, but I would like to use the last edited directory in `myDir` as a variable in my `bash` script. I know I could capture this via `ls -ltr myDir | tail -n1 | awk '{print $NF}'` but this parses `ls`. Is there a 'best way' to find the last edited directory inside of `myDir`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unix/Linux find and sort by date modified](http://superuser.com/questions/294161/unix-linux-find-and-sort-by-date-modified). There are a number of non-ls ways listed to sort directories there, and you need only use `head` or `tail` to grab the first or last one.

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this:

```
find /target_directory -type f -mtime -2
```

this will search for all files that have been modified in the target_directory and the sub_directory in the last 2 days.