# ZSH and globstar to match all files in subdirectories, but not directories

Tags: bash, zsh, globbing

I can do this:

```bsh
$ grep 'text' foo/* foo/**/*
```

but the problem with that is that it expands to list all the files AND directories, so I get a bunch of these errors:

```
grep: foo/a: Is a directory
grep: foo/bar/b: Is a directory
grep: foo/bar/c: Is a directory
grep: foo/bar/c/d: Is a directory
```

So my question is, **is there a globstar pattern I can use to only match files?**

Note that some directories can contain `.` and some files may not have an extension, so `**/*.*` doesn't work.

Also, this question is specifically about the ZSH globstar patterns, and not about other solutions, such as:

```
find foo -type f -exec grep -l "text" {} \;
```

or

```
grep -r 'text' foo
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `**/*(.)` to match only plain files or `**/*(-.)` to match only plain files and symlinks that point to plain files.

Or if you put `setopt globstarshort` in your `.zshrc` file, you can use `**(.)` and `**(-.)` instead.

Documentation:

- http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Recursive-Globbing
- http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers

Comment: Perfect answer, thanks! 