# AIX find file age in seconds no -printf with find

Tags: find, aix

AIX 7.2
Looking to recreate the below on AIX.

```
 find /etc -maxdepth 1 -iname "*conf" -type f -mmin +5  -printf '%p;%T@\n' | awk -F ';' -v time="$( date +%s )"  '{ print $1";"$2";" (time-$2 ) }'

/etc/rsyslog.conf;1640302499.0000000000;46381761
```

conf files are just and example of finding a list of specific files  that may be older than a set number of seconds.  Could be as low as 300 seconds or 43200 seconds or more.

Comment: Relating https://superuser.com/q/1609611/513541

Comment: While this question has been answered, the question is very, very unclear and I do not think it will be much value going forward unless it is edited to be more clear.

Comment: Probably an issue with the way I posted the question.  Basic requirements are to find a file or a list of files in AIX and print the list in seconds old.  The above find command shows the requirement.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find top N oldest files on AIX system not supporting printf in find command](https://superuser.com/questions/1609611/find-top-n-oldest-files-on-aix-system-not-supporting-printf-in-find-command)

Comment: Looked at https://superuser.com/questions/1609611/find-top-n-oldest-files-on-aix-system-not-supporting-printf-in-find-command  But Need to get the age of each file in seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I had to solve this on an AIX system, I'd again [lean on perl](https://superuser.com/a/1613901/513541). Since you're using `-maxdepth 1`, there's no real need to get into the File::Find module here. I came up with a perl script that uses two essential functions:

- [`glob`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc#glob-EXPR) to match the expected filename pattern
- [`stat`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc#stat-FILEHANDLE) to extract the mtime of the files

If the script finds files that match the pattern that have a last-modified time older than the expected age, it prints them in the semicolon-delimited format you gave. Beware that semicolons (and newlines and other whitespace) are allowable characters in filenames, so be careful when dealing with the output.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
# prints matching file mtime and age in seconds

use strict;

# expect 3 arguments:
# * a starting directory
# * a (quoted from the shell) wildcard for -iname
# * a cutoff age in seconds

if ($#ARGV != 2) {
  die "Usage: $0 [ dir ] [ pattern ] [ age ]"
}

my ($start_dir, $pattern, $age) = @ARGV;

unless ($age =~ /^\d+$/ && $age > 0) {
  die "$0: age must be a positive integer"
}

my $now = time();
my $cutoff = $now - $age;

foreach my $file (glob "${start_dir}/${pattern}") {
  next unless -f $file;
  my $mtime = (stat($file))[9];
  if ($mtime < $cutoff) {
    print "${file};${mtime};" . ($now - $mtime) . "\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: Very useful as it shows the concept is possible.  Might need some tweaks  Wildcard wouldn't work but partially specifying the file name with a wild card did work.
./getfiletime.pl /opt * 1
no output
./getfiletime.pl /opt fi* 1
/opt/file;1686773770;253

Comment: You would want to quote any wildcard you pass to this script, to protect it from being expanded by your shell.

Comment: Need to review this again.  Trying to pass the script an input file instead of passing parameters on the command line. 
File would contain multiple lines such as:
/etc *.conf 300
/tmp/app1 *.ext 300
/tmp/app2 *.gf  10000

Comment: Hi @mdtoro! It sounds like that's a bit different from your original question, so I'd suggest [asking a new question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask), linking to this one, and spelling out your new requirements.