# How to sort the results of a find command by the last access time?

Tags: find, timestamp

I find all the PDF files using

```
find . -type f -name *.pdf
```

How can I sort the files in the results by the last access time, and then by the last modification time?

By access time, I mean the time when the file is "opened", which, for PDF, typically means the file being opened in Adobe Acrobat.

Comment: Side note: [do not use `-name *.pdf`](https://superuser.com/q/1217773/432690).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unix/Linux find and sort by date modified](https://superuser.com/questions/294161/unix-linux-find-and-sort-by-date-modified)