# How to reorder folders in a directory in Linux?

Tags: linux, shell

I am new to Linux and am supposed to write a shell script to reorder the folders in a directory on the basis of ctime. The place where i am stuck is sorting the folders physically.

I have tried the following approaches:

1. I was using combinations of ls sort command under an impression that it also changes the physical order but it is not affecting the order only listing the result.
2. Using sort command alone hangs the terminal and then I am left with no other option other than canceling the command.

Kindly provide some reference for physical reordering of the folders. I have gone through articles but they were not much helpful.

What I am trying to achieve is to sort the folders in the directory on basis of last modified time. The main concern here is not how to extract time details of a folder in linux but what command can be helpful in sorting the folders physically on basis of last modified time.

Commands I have tried:

```
du -m --max-depth 1 | sort -rn
ls -1 | sort
ls -la | sort -k 1
```

Comment: Directories have no intrinsic order. The order will depend on the system locale. By "reordering", do you mean listing the directories and sorting them? Please [edit] your question and explain your task more clearly, and also show the scripts/commands you have already tried.

Comment: Please check . I have done the edits .

Comment: @slhck: They frequently do, and it depends on the filesystem. In most cases the order is _not_ changeable by the user, so I hope the OP really meant "reorder the _folder list_" as in `ls -ltc`...

Comment: @grawity You're of course right. I guess I should have been more precise. They have a physical order depending on how the filesystem indexes them (e.g., some sort of tree), but I was assuming the case of just doing a directory listing, where it's usually lexicographical.

Comment: By "physical" do you mean "visual"?  Are you trying to change the order the items are listed in a Nautilus window?  Please edit the question to include the Linux distribution (Ubuntu, for instance).

Comment: Yes visual order of the folders in the directory . I have  GNU/Linux installed on my server where i wan to perform this .

Comment: Since the folder order cannot be changed on disk, I have to assume the assignment is to display them in the correct order. take a look at this question: https://superuser.com/questions/147027/how-can-i-sort-the-output-of-ls-by-last-modified-date

Comment: The folder order cannot be changed on the disk ? I was.looking for this only. Anyways thank you . I will try some different approach then

Comment: I am voting to close the question unless it is [edit]ed with the information given in the comments below. As it stands it's not answerable, as it is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to list the contents of a directory by ctime, @grawity is correct, use

```
ls -ltc
```

If you want to list the contents of a directory based on the filesystem tree structure, you are wanting to sort by inode.  You can do that using

```
ls -li | sort
```

If you want something else, please provide a sample input and a sample output.

Hope this helps

Comment: I have tried these. The thing is I want to sort the folders in the directory and not just display them .

Comment: What do you mean by "sort the folders in the directory and not just display them"?  What are you looking to do once the folders in a given directory have been sorted?

Comment: The thing I am trying to achieve is sort the folders in a directory and then move the folders to another directory in a sorted order. Let me explain the scenario . We have a source folder where in we get documents per customer. For each customer we make a folder and then place his documents in those folder . Now we want to pick up folders in fcfs fashion i.e folder created first must be given priority . The approach that I have been asked to implement is first sort the folders in the source directory , then move these folders to a second directory with some additional conditions .

Comment: Good.  Additional information.  That is helpful.  Could you provide sample input and sample output as well?  That will give us an even better idea of what you are trying to accomplish.  If you want to supply things like creation times, modified times, etc, please do so.  The more details you give us, the better we will be able to help you.

Comment: @NishantSingh You should really edit your question and explain *this* – your original question really does not make a lot of sense without this information. Please also briefly read: http://xyproblem.info/